# Python Application Structure with 2 mains/processes

Tags: python, structure, popen, python-3.5

This is probably a super simple answer but I'm new to creating my own python application and packages.  I am fairly familiar with languages like C++ and C# and their libraries.

I am trying to construct a python package which I except to be run as like a simple executable.  I have supporting modules for this application which are simply classes that get instantiated and called.  However I do have an issue.  I have two main functions.  My reason behind this is that I have one part of the program which consists of simple for loop that instantiates one of the classes and then given specific details about this class (input coming into it etc) I create a Popen instance with the call 'python smartinterface.py' and smartinterface.py contains the other main function.  I am wondering how I could structure this the best.  Should I create two different packages and figure out how to link my modules containing the classes in since both processes depend on the same classes or am I doing something wrong with Popen?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that.

```
import asyncio, random


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

@asyncio.coroutine
def second_task():
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.5 + random.random())

@asyncio.coroutine
def main_task():
    while True:
        # do somthing
        loop.create_task(consume())


loop.create_task(main_task())
loop.run_forever()
```

Another example using a task Queue (I think it is better):

```
import asyncio, random

task_queue = asyncio.Queue()

@asyncio.coroutine
def task_producer():
    while True:
        yield from task_queue.put(random.random())
        yield from asyncio.sleep(random.random())

@asyncio.coroutine
def task_consumer():
    while True:
        value = yield from task_queue.get()
        print("returne value: ", value)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(task_producer())
loop.create_task(task_consumer())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: I understand that very well and I am using that.  I have my first file called startmonitor.py which runs fine. However this program calls my smartinterface.py with Popen which also contains a main function.  startmonitor.py is essentially a process that I want to continuously check something (say a file) and when the file has the necessary requirements, spin up another process running the other script I want this script to be able to end and have startmonitor resume. The only clean way I saw to do this was creating another process. It could be done other ways but I feel that they are not smart